# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isBatchingLegacy') | Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

when I run `npm run dev` I find this error, here this error is occour when I generate extension.

This way i used
`npm init @shopify/app@latest cd your-app npm run shopify app generate extension`

**Error:**
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isBatchingLegacy')                                                 at ensureRootIsScheduled (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\shopify-app\modern-investment-app\node_modules\react-reconciler\cjs\react-reconciler.development.js:17731:35)                                                                                   at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\shopify-app\modern-investment-app\node_modules\react-reconciler\cjs\react-reconciler.development.js:17636:5)                                                                                    at Object.updateContainer (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\shopify-app\modern-investment-app\node_modules\react-reconciler\cjs\react-reconciler.development.js:21022:5)                                                                                   at Ink.render (file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/shopify-app/modern-investment-app/node_modules/ink/build/ink.js:205:20)    at render (file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/shopify-app/modern-investment-app/node_modules/ink/build/render.js:19:14)      at renderString (file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/shopify-app/modern-investment-app/node_modules/@shopify/cli-kit/dist/private/node/ui.js:38:22)                                                                                                   at renderOnce (file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/shopify-app/modern-investment-app/node_modules/@shopify/cli-kit/dist/private/node/ui.js:7:33)                                                                                                      at renderFatalError (file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/shopify-app/modern-investment-app/node_modules/@shopify/cli-kit/dist/public/node/ui.js:198:12)                                                                                               at handler (file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/shopify-app/modern-investment-app/node_modules/@shopify/cli-kit/dist/public/node/error.js:113:5)                                                                                                      at file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/shopify-app/modern-investment-app/node_modules/@shopify/cli-kit/dist/public/node/error-handler.js:27:20                                                                                                    C:\Users\USER\Desktop\shopify-app\modern-investment-app\node_modules\react-reconciler\cjs\react-reconciler.development.js:17731                                                                                                                       if ( ReactCurrentActQueue$1.isBatchingLegacy !== null) {                                                                                            ^                                                                                                                                                                                                             TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isBatchingLegacy')                                                 at ensureRootIsScheduled (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\shopify-app\modern-investment-app\node_modules\react-reconciler\cjs\react-reconciler.development.js:17731:35)                                                                                   at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\shopify-app\modern-investment-app\node_modules\react-reconciler\cjs\react-reconciler.development.js:17636:5)                                                                                    at Object.updateContainer (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\shopify-app\modern-investment-app\node_modules\react-reconciler\cjs\react-reconciler.development.js:21022:5)                                                                                   at Ink.unmount (file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/shopify-app/modern-investment-app/node_modules/ink/build/ink.js:262:20)                                                                                                                           at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:525:35)                                                                               at EventEmitter.emit (node:domain:489:12)                                                                               at emit (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\shopify-app\modern-investment-app\node_modules\signal-exit\index.js:105:13)              at process.processEmit [as emit] (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\shopify-app\modern-investment-app\node_modules\signal-exit\index.js:193:7)                                                                                                              at process.exit (node:internal/process/per_thread:192:15)                                                               at process. (file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/shopify-app/modern-investment-app/node_modules/@shopify/cli/dist/index.js:12:13)                                                                                                                                                                                                                              Node.js v18.16.0

I want to run this shopify app using `npm run dev`